# Multithreaded/multiprocess windows service

Tags: c#, memory, windows-services

I created a multithreaded service to perform image processing. Everything worked fine until one of our clients installed the product in a 16 process server with lots of memory. Now the service throws lots of out of memory errors, which is understandable because processes can only get 1.5GB of memory regardless of how much is installed.

What is the accepted solution for this situation? Should this service instead spawn off a separate worker process? Should I have one worker process per CPU talking via named pipes to the main service?

EDIT we are running on a 64bit server, but can't target x64 because of imaging libraries limitations

Thank you

Comment: Is this a 64-bit machine? If yes, then build your assembly to target x64, not x86.

Comment: Yes it is, and unfortunately I can't target x64 because there are no imaging libraries that can run on that platform as of yet. We use Leadtools.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Comment: @Kiquenet - /LARGEADDRESSAWARE was the option that worked the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this. These are some of the options:

1. Link your .exe with [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). That will give your app up to 3 Gig of RAM, and no other changes are required.
2. Ask your software vendor who provided you with 32-bit binaries for 64 bit version.
3. Move your 32-bit dependencies out-of proc (e.g communicating via COM or WCF), and change your EXE architecture to 64 bit.
4. Spawn new processes for each execution action, rather than threads.
5. Convert your code to use [Address Windowing Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Options #1 and #2 are the easiest to implement, #5 is most difficult.

EDIT
I noticed `C#` tag in your question. For managed apps you can still use Large Address Aware flag using [EditBin.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d25ddyfc.aspx).

Comment: On 64 bit Windows a large address aware application will actually have access to the entire 4 GB address space.

Comment: Thank you. Option 3 wouldn't give me much because the code blowing up is the one that has to be 32bit. I don't have option 2 unfortunately. Option 4 seems to be viewed with skepticism when doing it from a windows service. Now on option 1 - is that possible for a .net application?

Comment: @Brian -- from my personal experience last time I did it I was able to allocate 2.5 Gig. Not quite entire 4 Gig, but definetely more than 2 Gig default limit.

Comment: @Otávio Décio, - Yes, you can use EditBin to fix up the application after it is built.

Comment: @SevaTitov: When you say allocate, I assume you're talking about the managed part of your application. The process gets the entire 4 GB address space, but obviously that holds the .NET runtime as well as your application. So your managed application will not be able to allocate 4 GB on its own. The process can use 4 GB. I was just pointing out that the OS doesn't need to use any part of the address space as is the case on the 32 bit OS.